# Lua attempt to call nil

Tags: lua, null, computercraft

So I have this Lua script :

```
function dispTanks()
    mon.setCursorPos(offsetPos, 1)
    mon2.setCursorPos(offsetPos,1)

    for i=1, #machines do   -- RC Tanks
        --------------------------------------------
        if string.find(machines[i], "rcirontankvalvetile")
           or
           string.find(machines[i], "rcsteeltankvalvetile") then                        
            if peripheral.isPresent(machines[i]) then
                periph = peripheral.wrap(machines[i])

                fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity, fluidID = marik.getTank(periph)                            

                if fluidName == nil then
                    -- does not display empty tanks
                elseif fluidName ~= nil then
                    mon2.setTextColor(tc)
                    x,y = mon2.getCursorPos()
                        mon2.setCursorPos(offsetPos, (y+1))
                        mon2.clearLine()
                    -- marik.cString(offsetPos,(y+1), tc, right, " ")
                    nameFL = split(marik.comma(fluidName), " ")
                    nameFL = nameFL[0]
                    mon2.write("Tank (" .. nameFL .. ") :  " .. marik.getBuckets(fluidAmount) .. " buckets") 
                end
             end
         end
     end
end
```

Now it gives a error at this line :

```
nameFL = split(marik.comma(fluidName), " ")
```

The error is: `attempt to call nil`.

Now, I am a beginner in Lua and this isn't my script but a free to use script and I have no idea how to fix this.

**EDIT**

So before I added the split section this was the result the script should give :

[image]

The problem was I wanted to change the names ( ardite.molten ) to Ardite and a friend said I needed to use split, so I added the following :

```
function firstToUpper(str)
    return (str:gsub("^%l", string.upper))
end
```

and

```
nameFL = split(fluidName, " ")
nameFL = nameFL[0]
```

And changed : `mon2.write("Tank (" .. marik.comma(fluidName) .. ") : " .. marik.comma(fluidAmount) .. " / " .. marik.comma(fluidCapacity) .. " mb (" .. marik.getBuckets(fluidAmount) .. " buckets)")`
to : `mon2.write("Tank (" .. nameFL .. ") :  " .. marik.getBuckets(fluidAmount) .. " buckets")`

which gives me the error :[image: http://puu.sh/a51QI/a848facf1b.png]

Comment: You seem to be using ComputerCraft, which does have `marik.comma`, and so the problem is `split`.

Comment: lhf Yes i'm using computercraft. marik.comma is a include file in the program. because i normally used marik.comma(fluidName) inside the mon2.write( it worked but outside the mon2.write it isnt working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the `split` function does not exist or the `comma` function of `marik`

EDIT:

What I think what you try to do is get everything before the dot instead of the full name right?

In that case you can do this:

replace these lines

```
nameFL = split(marik.comma(fluidName), " ")
nameFL = nameFL[0]
```

with this:

```
nameFL = marik.comma(fluidName):match("[^.]*")
```

You don't need a split for this. what this does is pattern matching and in this case it matches to everything until the first dot

Comment: `function firstToUpper(str)
    return (str:gsub("^%l", string.upper))
end
 `

This is the split function right?

Comment: that is not the split function. it's a firstToUpper function just as it says it makes the first letter of a string uppercase.

Comment: ooooh my bad, so maybe a noobie question but how do i make a split function out of this?

Comment: It worked thanks! Now how do i use the firstToUpper function in it?

Comment: wrap it all in firstToUpper to make the first uppercase, so it would be `nameFL = firstToUpper(marik.comma(fluidName):match("[^.]*"))`

Comment: Thanks that worked to! Now i forgot to ask something. Do u maybe know why i get double results? It only should show 1 of each and not 2. (so 1 ardite 1 cobalt etc)

Comment: can't help you with that

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will make a new topic for that then. I flagged your post as answer!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe lua has a built in `split` function, and it needs to be defined yourself. Since you say you got this script from an external source, they may have defined it elsewhere.

Try reading this page for some ideas: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

If split is indeed defined, then the only other possibility is that the `comma` function is undefined, in which case you would need to define it inside `marik`.